# Disable Multi-line Input on Textarea

Tags: html, text, input, field

I know I could use a text input field but for certain logical reasons I'm wondering if this is possible.  I'm sure I could use JavaScript to disable enter or something like that but I'm more curious whether it's possible with straight HTML.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a text input and set the height.

Comment: I like this thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this kind of thing without Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried the rows thing and it didn't work.  Thanks, though, brother!